# Bash Script : Printing success or failure on while loop

Tags: bash, loops, if-statement, while-loop, break

How to print "SUCCESS" only  one time after successfully execution of the complete while loop. 
if any error occurs during the loop then exit the loop and print "FAILED"

NOTE :- My code is printing success each time with the loop, I just want to print it one time, once the entire while loop is successfully executed

Comment: Can you show us some code?

Comment: Use a boolean flag, or a counter

Answer (score 0):

```
result='NOTHING TO DO'
if <condition>; then
  result=SUCCESS
  while <same condition>; do
    <task>
    if <error condition>; then
      result=FAILED
    fi
  done
fi
echo $result
```

(This assumes that never entering the while loop counts as `NOTHING TO DO`, ever failing the task counts as `FAILED`, and doing the task at least once and succeeding in the task for every iteration counts as `SUCCESS`.)

Comment: This will print nothing if `<condition>` evaluates to `false` from the very beginning. You should perhaps initialize `result` as `"SUCCESS"` only once before the `while` loop.

Comment: I know this would work in some cases. But my case is that if it enters in the loop . what if there is some error occurs during the loop . Then it should give result as failed and if it completes all the loops successfully and exit afterwards then it should give the result as success.

Comment: i've adapted the answer to your comment. (i removed the `break`, assuming that you want to go ahead with all loop iterations even if the task fails during some iterations.)